# Find out home path of web app using Javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, razor

I have a .NET MVC5 application using C#, HTML and Javascript.

I need to know the link of the host so I can send a specific file in a specific folder to the user.

In my local computer, when I test and develop the application, the path the app uses is the following:

```
localhost:1234/Home/Scripts/myScript.js
```

However, in the real deployment server, the path changes:

```
www.superhost.com/Apps/MyApp/Home/Scripts/myScript.js
```

I am trying to send this file to the user with the following JQuery, when a button is clicked:

```
$("a.btn.btn-default").click(function () {  
        download("/Scripts/myScript.js");  //download is a personal function, unimportant
        return false; //prevent browser defualt behavior
    });
```

The problem is that when I click the button, I get in the consolo an erorr  - 404 error, which means the server is not finding the file.

In fact the server is searching for the file on the path "/Scripts/myScript.js", but the file is in "Apps/MyApp/Home/Scripts/myScript.js".

How do I make my javascript smart enough to figure the correct path?

Comment: Remove the leading `/` from your download path.

Comment: @Qwerty: That will make it page relative.

Comment: I understand the question now.

Comment: I assumed you were using Razor for my answer below (as you said MVC 5), but you can also do something similar in ASPX if needed.

Comment: @Qwerty: I am usingn your solution and it works ! Please post it as an aswer so I can accept it !

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie: Your answer also works indeed! Worhty of kudos++! It turns out that page relativness was all I needed !

Comment: Beware of page-relative URLs in Razor as they may result in the wrong location.

Comment: @Flame_Phoenix Great then! :)

Comment: Note that using a page relative solution will fail on any default page URL: e.g  `/` vs `/home/index/` vs `/home/` which are all *the same page*, but different URLs and relative paths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the leading `/` from your download path.

You actually don't need an absolute path (and to know server's home folder) to access a file, target it relatively from the page you invoke the download from.

note: If you are using page relative paths, you must make sure you don't move the page the download script is executed from.

Comment: The downside of this approach is of course that the relative path has to be known in advance (how many levels back before drilling down) and the page depth it is used from cannot change or it will break. e.g. it will fail from `/` or `/home/` but work from `/home/index` even though they are the same page.

Answer (score 3):

One solution I use a lot is to inject a site-root URL into the page using something like this:

```
<body data-root="@Url.Content("~/")">
```

Which converts to the actual website base URL at runtime.

You then use that injected value, from all jQuery code, using:

```
var root = $('body').data("root");
```

You can simply prepend that to any relative URLs to make them work correctly:

```
 $("a.btn.btn-default").click(function () {  
    download(root + "Scripts/myScript.js");  //download is a personal function, unimportant
    return false; //prevent browser defualt behavior
 });
```

**Note:** this approach *will* work in cases where the routing changes:

e.g  `/` vs `/home/index/` vs `/home/` which are all the same page, but different URLs

Answer (score 0):

I always use in my layout the next code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var rootUrl = "@Url.Content("~/")";
</script>
```

And when I need it, i use for example:

```
 $("a.btn.btn-default").click(function () {  
    download(rootUrl + "Scripts/myScript.js");  //download is a personal function, unimportant
    return false; //prevent browser defualt behavior
 });
```